# App Permissions pop-up for Location Services never shows on screen recorded video

Tags: iphone, video, app-preview

I know this is not a programming question but thought I would give it a try anyway. I have been unable to get a app screen recording to show popup in recording that user gets when starting app for first time. I can see the pop up clear as day but it never shows on recording.

Is there a trick to get this pop up to show? App Connect says it is required in the video...so kind of stuck. I have tried QuickTime Player, iPhone screen recording, etc to no avail. Running Catalina v10.15.6. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Wow, shocked no one else has seen this issue. Does anyone know when the App Store started requiring the app previews to be on a physical device and show this pop up? Even when I mirror my iPhone Xs to my Mac, the pop-up does not show...

Comment: Same issue. Apparently, it remains to be satisfied only with screenshots or record on a physical camera from another device)

Comment: @CAHbl463, Can you explain what you mean about satisfied? The Location permissions pop-up shows when taking a video on the simulator...but app store says it has to be a a video from a physical device...where the Location permissions pop-up never shows on video.

Comment: Here is another post on it with more detail... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63602041/ios-request-permission-dialog-not-showing-on-screen-recording-or-quicktime-video

Comment: "App Connect says it is required in the video" - If I understand correctly, you need to show the work of your application for the purpose of attaching to the appeal to Apple Support?
If so, then you can shoot video of the device with your app in hand using the camera of another device. (but only silently without comments =))
I personally did this and was approved.

Comment: My app is approved after following your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: I also cannot believe this new requirement. I spent ages trying to do a screen recording, and looking online for solutions about the location prompt always being hidden. I never would have thought it would come to trying to film myself using an app with another phone camera! Apple even say "You can use a screen recorder to capture footage of your app in use."....

Comment: I also found success with taking a screenshot of the location services alert, and editing that into the recording. It blended in well enough and they didn't seem to care about the lack of animation. Approved nonetheless!