# iOS Request permission dialog not showing on screen recording or quicktime video

Tags: ios, video-capture

Does anyone know when the App Store started requiring the app previews to be on a physical device and show this pop-up?

Even when I mirror my iPhone Xs to my Mac, the pop-up does not show. If no pop-up on video, app store rejects app preview.

Anyone know of a better way to get around this issue?

[image]

Another image that shows issue:

This pop-up NEVER shows on screen recording or mirroring....
[image: iPhone on left mirror image on right...see what is missing?]

Answer (score 3):

We have same problem. You have two options:

1. You can record the screen from another mobile or camera
2. You can use a previous iOS. We have checked that permission dialog can be screen recorded with iOS12

What was your solution?

Comment: As it needs to be on a real device, I do not think option 2 is particularly easy unless you have a load of devices each with different OS versions. Option 1 is often the only choice, and leads to pretty shaky results trying to type while filming yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  has been steadily, over the past 3'ish years or so, working on removing certain system sensitive controls from being displayed in that feed. My guess it's for `$SEKURITY` reasons, though it doesn't completely make sense, to me, what would be the attack vector that it attempts to prevent.

The location dialog is not the only case I know that it hides.  It originally started with them hiding even `***` in the password text fields, and hiding the keyboard in such input, as well.  Apparently it now expanded to location, and likely other system dialogs. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly few people seem to be discussing this.
I published an app last year (2021 / June) on 14.? which required the popup and it was accepted. Did this again with another app just after 15.? and I cannot get it past the apple store. Once they allowed me to post a video recording and I got it through, but since then ... no chance.
How are people getting their app through - I assume apple use the screen capture system to do their testing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but my app was accepted.
Surely screen recording does not work, but screen capture does. I have embedded a screenshot of the permission dialog into a video and submitted it for app review.